# asp.net vb.net textbox should not allow to change if disable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Am working on asp.net with using vb.net i have a one form where is some disable textbox am assign the value on page load.user some time change it using f12 or some another way. So i don't want to change it any way if textbox is disabled.
My textbox name is txtUsername which is disable on Page load

My Code is

```
txtUsername.Enabled=false
'here amn getting value from database.
Dim strName as string ="Xyz"
```

but some user change the name "abc" and click on save then it update my database.

So i don't want to change it.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the server code that updates the details? You can't prevent this at the client side, but on the server side you have the control, you can update only the fields that are expected to be changed by the user instead of all the fields.

Comment: in onclick event get value from database agine and Comparison with textbox.text

Comment: If the TEXTBOX is always going to be READONLY on THAT page..... Then it makes much more sense to use a LABEL instead!